# Get category under which product was purchased

Tags: php, events, magento

I have this task to do, but I'm stuck on it. Client wants to get a category name product was purchased at. This info normally is not set. So at first step I'm trying to capture event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and set a category for product.

So in my `Observer.php` I try to get current category, by:

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getName()
```

but it appears that `current_category` object is not set in Mage registry. How can I add a category to a product in a different way? (Note that, product may belong to many categories, I just need the one at which it was purchased).

Regards,
ventus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping this data in user session is not so good idea. There is another way.
On product page I add a hidden `input` tag with current category id, which can be received by `$product->getCategory()->getEntityId()`.

Second step is more difficult. Before I have added new field (attribute) to the `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` named `from_category` (my custom name ;)). Now I use observer for event `sales_quote_save_before` and I set to Quote Item my custom attribute.

To convert quote item to order item with my custom attribute I just added to config.xml `global` section:

```
<fieldsets>
  <sales_convert_quote_item>
    <from_category>
      <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
    </from_category>
  </sales_convert_quote_item>
</fieldsets>
```

Now I can use it on checkout.

Answer (score 1):

create your session object and store the Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); there then:

- you can get it even if the user has moved away to product page
- you can decide what to do if this is empty and the client has accessed the product page directly

of-course you can tell your client that this is not a foolproof solution and instead of this he might just set up funnels for google analytics and have the correct statistics of client whereabouts on the page